# try to save values in the filter after reloading the page in the django template

Tags: django, templates, filter

I try to save values in the filter after reloading the page in the Django template. My code:

```
                            <label for="structDivisions">Structural divisions</label>
                            <select id="structDivisions" class="form-select form-select-sm"
                                    name="struct_division">
                                {% for SD in struct_divisions %}
                                    <option value="{{ SD.id }}" {% if SD.id == struct_division.id %}
                                            selected {% endif %}>{{ SD }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
```

it doesn't work

also a tried like this:

```
                            <label for="structDivisions">Structural divisions</label>
                            <select id="structDivisions" class="form-select form-select-sm"
                                    name="struct_division">
                                {% for SD in struct_divisions %}
                                    <option value="{{ SD }}" {% if SD == struct_division.select %}
                                            selected {% endif %}>{{ SD }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
```

it doesn't work too

add view:

```
def ReportsFilterView(request):
    user = get_current_user(request)
    qs = CompletedWork.objects.filter(checked_by_head=True).filter(
        Q(worker__struct_division__head=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__management_unit__head=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__curator=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__management_unit__curator=user)
    )
    struct_divisions = StructuralDivisions.objects.filter(
        Q(head=user) |
        Q(management_unit__head=user) |
        Q(curator=user) |
        Q(management_unit__curator=user)
    )
    workers = CustomUser.objects.filter(
        Q(struct_division__head=user) |
        Q(struct_division__management_unit__head=user) |
        Q(struct_division__curator=user) |
        Q(struct_division__management_unit__curator=user)
    )
    workstype = WorksType.objects.filter(
        Q(available_to__head=user) |
        Q(available_to__curator=user)
    ).distinct()

work_notes_contains_query = request.GET.get('work_notes_contains')
work_scope_min = request.GET.get('work_scope_min')
work_scope_max = request.GET.get('work_scope_max')
period_min = request.GET.get('period_min')
period_max = request.GET.get('period_max')
struct_division = request.GET.get('struct_division')

# special for worker
worker = request.GET.get('worker')

if worker and worker != 'Choose...':
    middle_name = None

    try:
        last_name, first_name, middle_name = worker.split()
        try:
            worker_get_id = CustomUser.objects.get(last_name=last_name,
                                                   first_name=first_name,
                                                   middle_name=middle_name)
        except  ValueError:
            worker_get_id = None

    except ValueError:
        last_name, first_name = worker.split()
        worker_get_id = CustomUser.objects.get(last_name=last_name,
                                               first_name=first_name)


work_done = request.GET.get('work_done')

if is_valid_query_param(work_notes_contains_query):
    qs = qs.filter(work_notes__icontains=work_notes_contains_query)

if is_valid_query_param(work_scope_min):
    qs = qs.filter(work_scope__gte=work_scope_min)

if is_valid_query_param(work_scope_max):
    qs = qs.filter(work_scope__lte=work_scope_max)

if is_valid_query_param(period_min):
    qs = qs.filter(period__date__gte=period_min)

if is_valid_query_param(period_max):
    qs = qs.filter(period__date__lte=period_max)

if is_valid_query_param(struct_division) and struct_division != 'Choose...':
    qs = qs.filter(worker__struct_division__name=struct_division)

if worker:
    if is_valid_query_param(worker) and worker != 'Choose...':
        qs = qs.filter(worker=worker_get_id)

if is_valid_query_param(work_done) and work_done != 'Choose...':
    qs = qs.filter(work_done__name=work_done).filter(
        Q(worker__struct_division__head=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__management_unit__head=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__curator=user) |
        Q(worker__struct_division__management_unit__curator=user)
    )
```

context = {
'queryset': qs,
'struct_divisions': struct_divisions,
'workers': workers,
'workstype': workstype,
}

if 'button_export' in request.GET:
return export_report(request)

return render(request, 'reports_related_struct_unit.html', context)

my function looks like this. It's long filter =)
It works normally. what can I do?

Comment: please add the `views.py` for this filtering

Comment: added =) it's filter function from view.py

Comment: it seems the view okey ! maybe in the template in the form tag  you didn't pass `method="GET"`  something like this  `<form action="...." method="GET">`

Comment: i have like this: <form method="GET" , action=".">